# twisted: flush data after a global value is updated

Tags: python, twisted

I am working with a chat app and I would like the server to control to flush the data to clients or not by pressing a button. I tried to do that by updating a global variable to trigger a if statement that can flush the data. However it seems that even the global variable is updated, it still does not trigger the if statement as the debugging "print" is not working, how can i fix that?

Here is the code

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Rectangle
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.graphics.instructions import Instruction
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
import socket
from kivy.core.window import Window
import pygame
import random
from kivy.support import install_twisted_reactor
install_twisted_reactor()
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol, defer
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory

censored = 0
class MultiClientEcho(protocol.Protocol):



    def __init__(self, factory, app):
        self.factory = factory
        self.app = app

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clients.append(self)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        for client in self.factory.clients:
            storedmessage = self.factory.app.handle_message(data)

            global censored
            if censored ==1:
                print "send message"
                client.transport.write(storedmessage)


            elif censored ==2:
                print "banned message"
                client.transport.write("censored")


    def connectionLost(self,reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)

class MultiClientEchoFactory(protocol.Factory):
    protocol = MultiClientEcho
    def __init__(self,app):
        self.clients = []
        self.app = app

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return MultiClientEcho(self, self.app)

class ServerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.label = Label(text="server started\n")

        self.approve_btn = Button(text="approve")
        self.approve_btn.bind(on_release=self.send_message)
        self.banned_btn = Button(text="banned")
        self.banned_btn.bind(on_release=self.banned_message)
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing=10)

        reactor.listenTCP(8000, MultiClientEchoFactory(self))

        self.layout.add_widget(self.label)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.approve_btn)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.banned_btn)

        return self.layout

    def send_message(self, *args):
        global censored
        censored = 1
        self.label.text += "sent\n"
        print censored
        return censored

    def banned_message(self, *args):
        global censored

        censored = 2
        self.label.text += "censored\n"
        print censored
        return censored

    def handle_message(self, msg):
        self.label.text += "received:  %s\n" % msg
        return msg


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ServerApp().run()
```

Comment: I assume the global variable is named `censored` and the debugging print statements you're talking about are `print "send message"` and `print "banned message"`. Right?

Comment: @gus42 yes that's correct

Comment: The API documentation for `dataReceived`says: "Called whenever data is received." So your `if` statements will be called only when data is incoming - is this possible?

Comment: @gus42 ah i see, so in that case i should build another class like "senddata" and pass the if statement there?

Comment: I don't think you need another class. A `senddata` method in `MultiClientEcho` or `ServerApp` could be sufficient. But I have to admit that I'm no expert for the twisted.internet.protocol API.

Comment: If you put a `senddata` method in `MultiClientEcho` or `ServerApp` you can implement it with a `censored` parameter to get rid off the global variable, e.g. `def senddata(self, censored)`.

Comment: Your help is deeply appreciated. Btw I just quickly added another method in the MultiClientEcho to test but it's still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76485/discussion-between-gus42-and-jessica-tsui).